# Algorithmacally speed up string slice operation - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Let's say I have a pretty large text document.
I need to imitate copy and paste operation of a text editor.

More concretely,
I want to write two functions copy(i,j) and paste(i), where i and j represent indices of characters in the text document.

Now, I understand that normal string slicing creates a new string object every time and doing something like

```
copy_text = str[i:j]
self.str = str[:i] + copy_text + str[j:]
```

will end up creating a lot of overhead of new string objects, given how many times we do a copy-paste function in a text editor.

How do I do it? Is it even possible?

I've looked into **memoryview**, where in they make use of a buffer, which may end up taking less time to execute given they create a zero-copy view of the original object. However, I want to do it algorithmacally and not play around with how strings are stored.
I've thinking on the lines of an array to store the string and use a B+ tree to store pointers to that string. I haven't been able to really materialize anything.

Look forward to your comments. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by creates a new string object everytime? And aren't you basically just updating/want to update your `self.str` with the contents you want to paste?

Comment: You've (re-)discovered one reason why 'real' text editors don't (generally) use an array to store long texts.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480980/whats-a-better-way-to-store-text-for-a-word-processor/ for further hints.